# using SOBJECT Tree resource in REST API Call

Tags: rest-api

I Was of view, through rest API , only single record can be created in SFDC
but this link has left me intrigued

[Create Multiple records Via Rest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm)

Through CURL using above tree resource, I'm able to create multiple records via Rest, at once . 
But I've question, how can I use this tree resource in JAVA Program  to create records? Is this possible ?

I was trying something like this :

```
  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

  // Parser parsing  JSON File having multiple records
 Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/ABCuser/Documents/CURL/NewAccount.JSON"));

   httpclient = new HttpClient();
   PostMethod mypost = new PostMethod(uri);
   String jsonText = obj.toString();
   System.out.println("\n_JSON TEXT=" + jsonText);
   mypost.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken); 
   mypost.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(jsonText, "application/json", "UTF-8"));
   int response=httpclient.executeMethod(mypost);
```

At last , it just throws error  with error code 404:

> [{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not
>   exist"}]

my question : My reason is, if this works in CURL, then it should be working in JAVA also, but I don't know, how I should proceed.

Comment: Let us know the endpoint you are using in Java Program. Please make sure that it has proper instance name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in java. I tried your code and it is working. As per my observation only thing which could be culprit here is the uri. 
Below is the code snippet where I have mentioned uri directly.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

               // Parser parsing  JSON File having multiple records
               Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("JsonData.json"));

               HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
               PostMethod mypost = new PostMethod("https://kmforce-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/composite/tree/Account/");
               String jsonText = obj.toString();
               System.out.println("\n_JSON TEXT=" + jsonText);
               mypost.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " +"<myssessionid>"); 
               mypost.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(jsonText, "application/json", "UTF-8"));
               int response=httpclient.executeMethod(mypost);
               System.out.println(response);
               System.out.println("Response-->"+mypost.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }
}
```

**Below is the output:**

```
{
    "hasErrors": false,
    "results": [
        {
            "referenceId": "ref1",
            "id": "0019000001bslYJAAY"
        },
        {
            "referenceId": "ref2",
            "id": "0019000001bslYKAAY"
        },
        {
            "referenceId": "ref3",
            "id": "0019000001bslYLAAY"
        },
        {
            "referenceId": "ref4",
            "id": "0019000001bslYMAAY"
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if you face any issue here.

Comment: Wow thanks for pointing out mistake .. error was indeed in uri..... I was pointing to v32.0 in uri which seemed to be causing problem